# Can you 'mount' an Ubuntu Touch (nexus 4/7) device as a disk?

Tags: windows, mount, ubuntu-touch, mac, mtp

Is it possible to mount a Nexus 4 or Nexus 7 which is running the latest Ubuntu Touch dev preview as a disk via USB with MTP or similar?

I can adb and/or ssh into these devices, no problem, but I want to try to 'drag and drop' videos and other documents from my Macbook Air (running 10.8.4) or from my PC (running either Windows 7 or Ubuntu).

Anyone know if it's possible? Am I missing something blatant?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes. This can be done easily over SSH. I have used both Nautilus (std. with Ubuntu) and SecureFX (Windows, Ubuntu, OS-X, etc.). *Once you have installed SSH server (**`sudo apt-get install openssh-server`**) on the device, it is quite straight forward.*

Comment: Hi david6, as already mentioned I already have SSH access but what steps do I use to mount the device as a disk within the GUI of the computer it is plugged into?

Comment: From Ubuntu, you can 'Connect to Server'. This will establish SSH, and provide GUI access. *Update your question.* **What are you trying achieve, on what platform, with what tools?**

Comment: Hi David, I was unaware of 'Connect to Server' in Ubuntu, thank you. I would like to know how to do it in Mac OS X and Windows as well, please.